# Добавление данных в разных запросах в одну строку

Tags: mysql, sql

Можно как-то через определенный период времени (в разных запросах), добавлять данные в одну строку?

```
INSERT INTO (december) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO (march) VALUES (2);
```

Это создает две строчки, как сделать чтобы создавалась одна? Только без `WHERE december = 1`.

Comment: Как подметил andrew68, конкретнее пожалуйста ))

Answer (score 2):

А два раз одну и  ту же строчку вы не сможете вставить =) Первый раз - insert, второй update - и без where вам не обойтись

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT ...");
$insId = mysql_insert_id();

{whatever}

$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ... WHERE id = ".$insId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретней вопрос

```
INSERT INTO (december, march) VALUES (1, 2);
```